# How to show sequence of probability measures is tight?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

> Suppose that $\{\mu_n\}$ is a sequence of probability measures on $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{R})$ such that
> \begin{align*}
> \sup_n\int x^2d\mu_n<\infty
> \end{align*}
> Prove that $\{\mu_n\}$ is tight, namely, for any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $M>0$ such that $\mu_n(-M,M)>1-\varepsilon$, for all $n\ge1$.

A sequence of random variables $\{X_n\}$ being tight here means
\begin{align*}
\lim_{c\to\infty}\sup_nP(|X_n|>c)=0
\end{align*}

I know that if we let $\{X_n\}$ be such that $P_{X_n}=\mu_n$ for all $n$, then
\begin{align*}
EX_n^2=\int x^2d\mu_n<\infty\quad\text{for all $n$}
\end{align*}
So, given any $\varepsilon>0$ there exists an $M_n>0$ such that $\frac{EX_n^2}{M_n}<\varepsilon$. Then taking $M:=\sup\limits_n M_n$, we have
\begin{align*}
\frac{EX_n^2}{M}<\varepsilon\quad\text{for all $n$, correct?}
\end{align*}
Now, if we knew that $E|X_n|\le E|X_n|^2$, then we would have
\begin{align*}
\mu_n(-M,M)&=P_{X_n}(-M,M)\\
&=P(X_n\in(-M,M))\\
&=P(|X_n|<M)\\
&=1-P(|X_n|\ge M)\\
&\ge1-\frac{E|X_n|}{M}\quad\text{by Markov}\\
&\ge1-\frac{E|X_n|^2}{M}\\
&>1-\varepsilon,\quad\text{as we wished to show.}
\end{align*}
But there is no reason that $E|X_n|\le E|X_n|^2$ here, as these random variables are completely arbitrary, apart from the fact that they are distributed as $\mu_n$. I also thought about trying something like
\begin{align*}
E|X_n|&=E|X_n|\mathbb{1}_{\{|X_n|\le1\}}+E|X_n|\mathbb{1}_{\{|X_n|>1\}}\\
&\le 1+E|X_n|^2
\end{align*}
Which would give, following the same steps as above,
\begin{align*}
\mu_n(-M,M)&=P(|X_n|<M)\\
&=1-P(|X_n|\ge M)\\
&\ge1-\frac{E|X_n|}{M}\quad\text{by Markov}\\
&\ge1-\frac{1+E|X_n|^2}{M}\\
&=1-\frac{1}{M}-\frac{E|X_n|^2}{M}\\
&>1-\frac{1}{M}-\varepsilon,\quad\text{which isn't quite what we want.}
\end{align*}
Do you see any way to fix this approach or is there a better way to solve this problem? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can't you just use $\mu_n( \mathbb R \setminus [-M,M]) = \mathbb P(|X_n| >M) \le \frac{\mathbb E[X_n^2]}{M^2} \le \frac{K}{M^2}$, where $K=\sup \mathbb E[X_n^2]$ and then choose $M$ big enough?

Comment: Ohhhhh, I just realized that we can just square both $|X_n|$ and $M$ in the inequality and not need to call on Chebyshev, where we would need to know that $EX_n=0$, thank you!

Comment: By the way, $(\mathbb E|X|^p)^{\frac{1}{p}} \le ( \mathbb E|X|^q)^{\frac{1}{q}}$ is true for $0<p<q<\infty$ for any random variable. So in your case $\sup \mathbb E|X_n| < \infty$, too. (It is called Lyapunov's inequality)

Comment: Ahh, that is good to know, thanks!